# Add condition base on parent's parent data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a problem converting query to Laravel Eloquent.
This is the query:

```
SELECT cat.id,
       reg.title AS region_title,
       reg.region_code,
       catlang.title,
       catlang.description,
       cat.status
FROM categories AS ca
JOIN regions As reg
      ON cat.region_id = reg.id
JOIN category_language_region As catlang
      ON cat.id = catlang.category_id
          AND reg.language_id = catlang.language_id;
```

That is working in Postgres and as you can see, I added additional condition for joining category_language_region `reg.language_id = catlang.language_id`. I'm stuck on converting it to Laravel Eloquent Builder.

This is the schema for it

- Table Language: id, code
- Table Region: id, code, language_id
- Table Category: id, status, region_id
- Table Category Language Region: id, title, category_id, language_id

This is what I tried

```
$results = Category::with([
    'region' => function($query){
        $query->select('title', 'id', 'region_code', 'language_id');
    },
    'categoryLanguages'
])->select(['categories.*'])
->whereIn('region_id', $region_ids);
```

But it returns all category language region. I need add to condition to select only `category_language_region.language_id` equal to selected `region.language_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this solution using the Query Builder based on your given code:

```
DB::table('categories as cat')
->select([
    'cat.id',
    'reg.title as region_title',
    'reg.region_code',
    'catlang.title',
    'catlang.description',
    'cat.status'
])
->join('regions as reg', 'cat.region_id', '=', 'reg.id')
->join('category_language_region as catlang', function($join) {
    $join->on('cat.id', '=', 'catlang.category_id');
    $join->where('reg.language_id', '=', 'catlang.language_id');
});
```

Comment: It returns Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "catlang.language_id". and sql query. But when I run the return query in postgres, it is working fine

Comment: I changed $join->where to $join->on and it is working fine now. thank you